# Using Javascript for Background Image Change on Page Refresh - Responsive?

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design, background-image, page-refresh

I am new to javascript, but I am currently using javascript in my head tag that changes images randomly on page refresh. This has been working great. The javascript can be seen below.

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
    function changeImg(imgNumber)   {
        var myImages = ["image1.jpg", "image2.jpg", "image3.jpg", "image4.jpg"]; 
        var imgShown = document.body.style.backgroundImage;
        var newImgNumber =Math.floor(Math.random()*myImages.length);
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+myImages[newImgNumber]+')';
    }
    window.onload=changeImg;
```

Now I want to take it one step further and make the images responsive. I've tried a number of different tags via media queries, but nothing seems to work 100%. This particular page has a top section with a height of 310px, which is also where the images are displayed - they also have a height of 310px. Is this something I can do with CSS or CSS3? Or will I need to add additional javascript?

Thanks for the help in advance... my brain hurts!

Comment: In css, try `body {background-size : cover}`

Comment: Thanks, @Adeneo. I have tried that without any change. The images are only in the first section of the page, labeled by a div #first. Would you suggest I replace 'body' with 'first' in the javascript?